# How to use the word 'party' as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

I have an English worksheet where I am supposed to use the word "party" as an adverb.

"I went partying" - Is this correct? (It answers the question, "where did I *go* ?") I couldn't think of anything else...

Is the word "partying" used here a noun or an adverb of place?

My understanding is that if a verb is followed by a preposition and then a 'place', the 'place' is a noun. (For example: I went to the party. Here 'party' is a noun.) Is my understanding correct?

Comment: what has your research of 'partying' revealed

Comment: Are you sure the word wasn’t *partly*? Even [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/party) doesn’t list *party* as an adverb.

Comment: No... It's party.

Comment: We are asked to use it as a noun, verb and adverb. I figured out the noun and verb parts... Just the adverb part is confusing....

Comment: @lbf - "  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/partying " defines partying as a verb used without object: to go to or give parties, especially a series of parties (or)
to enjoy oneself thoroughly and without restraint; indulge in pleasure. But I don't think I meant to use it in the form of a verb. Or have I?

Comment: @GokulakrishnanShankar good.now incorporate your findings into you question.

Comment: If you must take *party* as an adverb, try to come up with a [verb, adjective or another adverb](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adverbs/what-is-an-adverb.html) that *party* could modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you realized in the comments, your sentence uses the word as a verb.

I think the worksheet has an error (they probably meant "adjective", as in ["a party leader"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/party)). Or it could just be poorly designed.

As a native speaker, I've never heard "party" used as an adverb, nor do I know of any derivatives of "party" that are adverbs. This is backed up by every regular English dictionary that I checked.

The one dictionary that does list it as an adverb is the Oxford English Dictionary (because it's a historical dictionary and contains some very rare words).

Although it's almost certainly not what the worksheet is looking for, there is one definition in the OED for "party" as an adverb (it just means "partly"), which is marked as "Now *rare* (only in *Heraldry*)". I found an example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_of_the_field):

> Common partitions of the field are:
>
> - *parted* (or *party*) *per fess* (halved horizontally)
> - *party per pale* (halved vertically)
> - *party per bend* (diagonally from upper left to lower right)
> - *party per bend [sinister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_and_sinister)* (diagonally from upper right to lower left)
> - *party per saltire* (diagonally both ways)
> - *party per cross* or *quarterly* (divided into four quarters)
> - *party per chevron* (after the manner of a chevron)
> - *party per pall* (divided into three parts in a **Y** shape)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that using "party" as an adverb is unusual, but it's not impossible:

> I fancy going clubbing this weekend, but I've got to go to my cousin's wedding. So instead of going nightclub dancing I'll be party dancing instead.

Of course this only works for people who dance differently in nightclubs and at parties...

Comment: That usage sounds to me more like a noun-modifier, which is either a noun used as an adjective, or a noun turned into an adjective; in either case not very adverbial.